# The loser has a 2 pair over a one pair

Tags: rules, reading-hands

[image: how]

How does rubina win ?
How does inclinations lose the hand. Inclinations seems to have 2 pair vs one pair.

Answer (score 7):

Both players have two pairs, as there is a pair of Kings on the board. Inclinations was ahead until the river paired the board.

Rubina's best five card hand is: K♥K♠6⋄6♣T⋄

Which beats Inclinations best five card hand: K♥K♠6♥6♣5⋄

The two pairs are equal in rank, so the fifth card acts as the tie breaker.

Also check my answer here, for a more in-depth explanation of how to determine who has the best hand: https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/4405/1084