# Kicker cards - and splitting pots

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, reading-hands

I don't understand that when sometimes I play, instead of a pot being split as I would anticipate, one one player gets the full pot.

Even if the best hand seems to be in the middle - i.e -  a pair.

I hold an ace and 6

my opponent holds an ace 7

but in middle there is 2, 2, q, 3, 4 (no flushes).

So wouldnt the best hand be split between us because we both have a 2 pair and a queen as a high card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tie breakers exist?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/what-tie-breakers-exist)

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted, it's a good question.

Comment: Poker hands have EXACTLY 5 CARDS, no more, no less. Your hand is 2-2-A-Q-6, his hand is 2-2-A-Q-7.

Comment: It likely was downvoted because this same question or one very like it is asked (and answered) every day. And because even a cursory Google search will answser it. The Wikipedia articles on Poker, in particular, are very clear on these points.

Answer (score 6):

In the example you give both players have 1 pair.  Poker is the best 5 card hand.  Your best hand would be 2,2,A,Q,6 your opponents best hand would be 2,2,A,Q,7.

Therefore his 7 would "out kick" your 6.

However, if the board was 2,2,3,3,Q

You both would share the best hand 2,2,3,3,A and the pot would therefore be split

Comment: But wouldn't the ace still beat the queen in the best overall 5 card hand? Why does the Ace not kick out the queen?

Comment: Again, poker hands have EXACTLY 5 CARDS, no more, no less. I should make this a keyboard macro since a question like this comes up here at least once a day.